# Use tikzmath in between connecting coordinates with the draw function

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, draw, tikzmath

If I understand correctly, the `\draw` function allows one to connect points with lines, and then (if the lines come back to the same point) fill the outlined shape. If one uses the `-- ( , )` command it will just draw a line from the previous point to this point. I would like to use the `tikzmath` function to generate points (just helpful when the points are on a curve defined by an elementary function) in a `foreach` loop and connect subsequent points. Below is an attempt to do that for a circle:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\def\npts{100}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) -- (0, 0)
    \foreach \num in {1, 2, ..., \npts}
    {
        \tikzmath{
            \xspace = 2*pi/\npts;
            \t1 = \xspace*(\num - 1);
            \x1 = sin(\t1);
            \y1 = cos(\t1);
        }
        -- (\x1, y1)
    }
    -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It seems like the `\tikzmath` command interrupts the `\draw` command in a way that makes it not compile. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, provide us a sketch about what you like to draw.

Comment: I would like the output of this tex file to be a circle of radius one centered at the origin. However, my question isn't so much "how do I draw a circle?" as "is it possible to draw a circle in this particular way?" Basically I'm wondering if there is a way to generate points for a curve in the middle of using the `\draw` function.

Comment: As you see, it is not possible on the your way. To suggest you working solution we should know, what is desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is at least one way: using evaluate (in place of \tikzmath ) inside the draw options and define two functions x(i) and y(i).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[
          evaluate={
               \npts=100;
               \xspace = 360/\npts; % 2pi=360
               %
               function x(\i){
                      \t=\xspace*(\i - 1);
                      return cos(\t);
                      };
             %
              function y(\i){
                     \t=\xspace*(\i - 1);
                      return sin(\t);
                     };
       }
           ] (0, 0) foreach \num in {1, 2, ..., \npts}
                      {
                        -- ({x(\num)},{y(\num)})
                      }
             -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! A follow-up Q: Does `\tikzmath` get me anything that evaluate doesn't? That is, are there math functions (e.g. hyperbolic cosine), logical functions (e.g. if statements), etc. that tikzmath can do that `evaluate` cannot?

Comment: `evaluate={<something>}` simply executes `\tikzmath{<something>}`